# How to make <div> fill whole screen except for navbars

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently using Bootstrap, using the following template they provide:

[Bootstrap Dashboard Template](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/)

I like the header/navbar, and the sidebar.  I have removed all the content in the "main space" `div`, leaving it blank. This is the `div`'s code (ignore the border; it's there for me to visualize what the `div` is doing):

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main"
     id="maps_canvas" style="border:2px solid red">
    <!-- a Google Maps embed would be here -->
</div>
```

My goal is to embed Google Maps in this whitespace.  To do this, I need to create a `div` that fills the entire whitespace.  Ideally, I would like the `div` to bind to the edges of the window, so it doesn't overflow / create any scrolling.   I found that by hard-setting my height, it would result in overflow if I resized my Chrome window for example. Is there a way to do this?

For example, look at http://www.renthop.com/.  They have a map that does what I'm looking to do - it locks to the bottom right of the screen.

---

EDIT:  This is a jquery problem.  Problem now is, I can't seem to get both these functions to run.  when I remove my $(document) function, the google function works no problem.  When I include it, the entire thing falls over:

```
        /*$(document).ready(function() {
                /*  confirm("im here");
                /*$('#map_canvas').css({'height': (($(window).height()) - 114)+'px'});

                $(window).resize(function(){
                $('#map_canvas').css({'height': (($(window).height()) - 114)+'px'});
                });
        });*/




 function initialize(){         

                var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');

                var map_options = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.749623,-73.9618013),
                zoom:12,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }

                var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: You will need to give the body and div a height of 100%, then use col-lg-12, this will make the bootstrap huge the edges no matter the size. Of course the stuff you put inside the div must fit as well. I think bootstrap adds some margin to col-lg-12 so you may need to remove that.

Comment: I've set the height of the body, the container, the row, and the div all to 100% and no dice.  now its only about an inch high.

Comment: Here is [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/RZb2D/) with the starting point you have described, so everyone can easily try editing it.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work @RoryO'Kane.  It still only gives me a 1 inch row that goes across the screen...

Comment: It wasn't meant to be an answer, just a reproduction of what you already have so that people can easily edit it and try to accomplish what you are asking for. Or do you mean that it doesn't correctly reproduce the code you are starting with?

Comment: @keynesiancross Make you add `height:100%;` to the `html` tag as well...

Comment: @RoryO'Kane - whoops my fault.  Thought that had a solution.

Comment: Why not start over and use a template like this? http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mad some changes to your HTML and CSS, one problem is because bootstrap floats items they do not like to fill a height 100%. You need to make the float container positioned absolute and its parent as relative to maintain it.  http://jsfiddle.net/RZb2D/3/

```
#maps_canvas {
 padding:0px;
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
}
.row {
 height:100%;
 position:relative;
}
```

Comment: You may need to make some tweaks to get it to perform exactly how you want, but this will get you started.

Comment: Thanks @TheHamstring.  I still can't seem to get it to work unfortunately. I've done what you have above, but now my google maps has basically collapsed into a 1px row that goes the width of the screen...

Comment: Can you throw what you have into JSfiddle? Something might be missing if what you have is a collapsed row.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't - but I think I have made progress.  Its a jquery thing.  Problem is, when I write this (edit above) in my .js file niether functions work.  When I remove my $(document) part, the google code works properly.

Comment: Ok - I got it (sort of).  Why on earth do I need to put:
<script type="text/javascript" src="mapsJS.js"></script>  at the end of my body in the .html document, as opposed to in the head?  Is it because the code trys calling up a div that hasn't yet been created?

Comment: Yes, if you are trying to use a element which hasn't yet been processed by the browser your javascript cannot find it. Same reason jQuery suggests to have the code in a document ready function.